# linear_congruential library in boost

Tags: c++, boost, random

I am trying to use `random::linear_congruential` in boost (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/random/random-generators.html#linear_congruential) to generate uniform random numbers. The declaration is defined as:

```
template<class IntType, IntType a, IntType c, IntType m, IntType val>
```

Does anyone know what the last parameter `IntType val` means? It is not documented and I could not find any reference. I am setting up my parameters as follows but don't understand how to set val:

```
random::linear_congruential<long, 39373L, 0, 2147483647L, ??> generator;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given seed = 1, the 10,000th value returned by the generator must be `val`. This is apparently a common practice among PRNG implementors to use the 10,000th value as a test.

Comment: what if I don't know the 10,000th value that will be returned? And if I don't want to set this value as it looks like it is required.

Comment: @user236215: I think it's only required for unit tests. The generator will be working and producing the same values regardless of what `val` is set to.